# Duplicated posts while using Infinite Scroll + random order

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll

I'm using wp_query with infinite scroll to display posts in a specific cpt archive page. When i set the 'orderby' to 'date', everything works ok, but when i change it to 'rand' the query returns the correct number of posts, but some of them are duplicated.

This is the code i'm using:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$loopb = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'my_post_type', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged, 'order' => 'rand' ) ); 
$value = get_field('thumbnail_sizing');
 ?>
<?php while ( $loopb->have_posts() ) : $loopb->the_post(); 

    $thumb_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'small-size' );

$full_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full-size' );
$thumb_img_ratio = 70; 
if (isset($thumb_img[1]) && isset($thumb_img[2]) && $thumb_img[1] > 0) {
    $thumb_img_ratio = $thumb_img[2] * 100/$thumb_img[1];
} ?>


<div class="mosaic">
    <a href="#" class="grayscale">
        <div class="mosaic__image" style="padding-top: <?php echo $thumb_img_ratio;?>%;">
            <img src="<?php echo $thumb_img[0]; ?>" data-src="<?php echo $full_img[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>">
        </div>

        <div class="meta">
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="flex_item">
                    <h2 class="meta_title"><?php the_field('name1');?> <span class="divider">&amp;</span> <?php the_field('name2');?></h2>
                    <hr class="separator">
                    <span class="cat">view image</span> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </a>
</div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Carry a random seed with you i don't know if `WP_Query` supports it but it would be `RANDOM(SEED)` (e.g. `RANDOM(1234)`) in straight`mysql`

Comment: Unfortunately i dont know how to do that :) . I did find this that has to do with random http://pastebin.com/K8nkAY34 , but it just sorts the posts by date again instead of random